# Why is boiling point of carbon tetrachloride greater than silicon tetrachloride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

$\ce{CCl4}$ and $\ce{SiCl4}$ both are non polar molecules thus London forces must be the only forces of interaction.

Then London forces are supposed to be greater in $\ce{SiCl4}$ due to its larger size and its boiling point should be higher than comparatively smaller $\ce{CCl4},$ but $\ce{CCl4}$ has higher boiling point.

The only explanation I got is the greater polarity of the $\ce{Si-Cl}$ bond. I don't understand how polarity of individual bonds in a non-polar molecules increases its boiling point.

Comment: The larger Si atom changes the outside shape of the molecule. I´ll guess that the "contact area" between neighbouring molecules in SiCl4 is less.

Comment: Interesting! That contrasts with b.p. of CF4 & Si4, −128 °C and −86 °C; and with CI4 and Si4, 171 °C and 287 °C, respectively, where the Si compounds have *higher* b.p., as opposed to 77 °C and 58 °C for the chlorides.

Comment: @karl As Si is larger  than C shouldn't the contact area be greater for sicl4

Comment: Carbon tetrachloride is more compact in shape. Try calculating the molar densities, and compare with the molecules' diameters.

Comment: @karl I asked the same thing. If ccl4 is smaller and lighter then why does it have a higher boiling point?

Comment: That´s not the point I am trying to make. If you scale down SiCl4 so the molecule has the same size as CCl4, how many of them are in the same volume? Or in other words, how good is the *packing* of both of them in the liquid state? Or you compare the unit cell volumes of the crystalline substances. My guess is that SiCl4 is not quite as "dense" as it looks, in terms of packing.