# Order of boiling point of group 14 halides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, halides, boiling-point

> Find out the species having lowest boiling point:
>
> (**A**) $\ce{SnCl4}$
> (**B**) $\ce{GeCl4}$
> (**C**) $\ce{SiCl4}$
> (**D**) $\ce{CCl4}$

I have considered the inert pair effect of $\ce{Sn}$ here which will make the compound $\ce{SnCl4}$ least stable (and perhaps the one with lowest b.p.) and hence came up with the answer being option **A**. But, when I checked the answer, it was option **C**.

Why was my assumption incorrect and what should be the way of approach here?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134794/why-is-boiling-point-of-carbon-tetrachloride-greater-than-silicon-tetrachloride

Comment: @Mithoron, the question is not answered there as well. And this one is quite different since I have asked about 4 of the elements of group 14 whereas the OP in the question that you linked asked for only two.

Comment: It's unanswered, but not different. The crucial point is that that for some reason CCl4 has higher boiling point then SiCl4. Unfortunately, you'd have to simply know it. While there have to be "reasons" for that, it's still an anomaly and no rule would let you guess it.

Comment: Thank you @Mithoron. I have to memorize it then.

Comment: @Sanu_012 You don't necessarily have to memorize it I guess. C has got a much greater capacity for catenation as compared to Si, and so the number of molecules weakly bonded together in CCl4 in the liquid state should be more than SiCl4,and hence,the former should have a higher boiling point.